# ¿Como proteger mis contraseñas en mi columna de usuarios?

Tags: sql-server, windows-forms, entity-framework-6

Estoy terminando de desarrollar mi aplicacion, pero ahora me surgio la necesidad de darle seguridad a las contraseñas de mis usuarios (y en especial la mia para evitar que modifiquen cosas como una fecha de vencimiento de licencia). ¿De que forma puedo cifrar una columna "contraseña", de modo que no se puedan leer cuando se genera la base de datos con una copia de restauracion (backup) ni tampoco cuando armo una lista y la llevo temporalmente a un `List` para preguntar si lo que ingresa el usuario coincide con alguno de los registros contraseña traidos desde mi base de datos que coincidieron con los usuarios que especifique que tienen autorizacion para acceder a X parte del programa?.

Foto de la tabla objetivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Foto de algunos registros de mi tabla (donde mi necesidad es proteger los campos de la columna contraseña):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, el proceso de cifrado debes realizarlo antes de almacenar las contraseñas en la base de datos. Si las has almacenado ya en texto plano, tienes un grave problema de seguridad. Existen diversidad de mecanismos para realizar la tarea. Tal como tienes tu pregunta es muy amplia, te invito a repasar [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Ya le agregue mas contenido, no se si cumple con los requisitos en cuestion o le agrego algo mas.

Comment: Revisa [el manual de SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data).

Answer (score 1):

Al hilo de lo que comenta @Orion, no es posible darte una respuesta clara a lo que propones. La base de datos almacena un string y no entiende de encriptación. Debe ser la aplicación que realiza el `INSERT`y `UPDATE`quien recoja la contraseña, la encripte y la guarde en el campo contraseña.

Tienes muchas opciones para hacerlo, pero dependerá del entorno y lenguaje de programación que utilices.

Comment: Gracias por la informacion! ¿tienes algun video o pagina que me recomiendes donde expliquen los metodos para realizar dicha encriptacion?

Comment: Depende del lenguaje que utilices, [Aqui](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/ASPDotNet/encryption-decryption-in-csharp.aspx?Id=109) tienes un ejemplo simple en C#